# array element not being traced by conditional statements but present when printed 

Tags: php

can someone help me in understanding why i'm not able to trace the 59th element of the array in conditional statements or in array search where as when i print the array contents it shows as 59th element.

```
<?php
//libxml_use_internal_errors(true);error_reporting(0);
ob_start();
$url = 'http://m.cricbuzz.com/cricket-archive/scorecard/10777/1';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$tds = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach ($tds as $td) {
    echo $td->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;

}
$page = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_flush();
$fp = fopen("output.html","w");
fwrite($fp,$page);
fclose($fp);

$content = file('output.html');
//First line: $content[0];
echo $content[59] .'<br><br>';
var_dump($content);
$batsmen1=array();$bowlers1=array();
$x=sizeof($content);
//echo "size of array = ".$x."<br>";

$d=array_search('Bowler',$content);echo '<br>'.$d;
if(in_array("C Gayle", $content)){echo 'found<br>';} else{echo 'ille<br>';}
$con=array();
for($i=0;$i<59;$i++)
{
if($content[$i]<>"Bowler")
{
array_push($batsmen1, $content[$i]);
//echo 'if<br>';
//echo $content[$i];
$con[$i]=$content[$i];
echo $con[$i];
}
elseif($content[$i]=="Bowler"){
echo 'else';
}
}
//var_dump($batsmen1);


 ?>
```

what i mean is 
`echo array_search('Bowler',$content);...elseif($content[$i]=="Bowler")...if(in_array("C Gayle", $content)){echo 'found<br>';} else{echo 'ille<br>';}` 
is not able to trace it

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: the issue is not with the position of the element in array as I've checked it till 100., what i mean is... i've clearly stated above in the question and `echo $content[59] .'<br><br>';` is printing that element

Comment: **update** $pieces = explode("Bowler", file_get_contents('output.html')); $zaq = explode("\n", $pieces[0]); foreach($zaq as $value) { echo 'the next elemnt is.. '.$value.'<br><br>'; } echo array_search('C Gayle', $zaq) .'hmmmmmmm'; if (in_array("C Gayle", $zaq)) { echo "C Gayle"; } else {echo 'trash';} still the same issue friends, `foreach` is able to print `$zaq` values but not bale to find the fifth element(starting from zero) of that i.e., 'C Gayle' but i can find it by echoing like `echo $zaq[5];`

Comment: there is an EDIT link right below the tags.

Comment: Do *not* edit to completely change the question after people have provided answers.  It invalidates all of the answers.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in PHP use 0-based indexing. The 59th element is accessed by `[58]`, not `[59]`. So if `echo $content[59]` does indeed echo "Bowler", then Bowler is the 60th element, not the 59th.

This means that:

```
echo $content[59] .'<br><br>';
```

And:

```
for($i=0;$i<59;$i++)
```

aren't totally compatible. Your `for` loop should go until `$i < 60`, not 59.

Comment: Sir, I've used all permutations possible. My issue is am not able to trace the element "bowler" through conditional statements, i can see it when printed.

Comment: `echo $content[59] .'<br><br>';` prints the element 'bowler' but am not able to detect it by conditional statements. All I need is to make two arrays of which one should contain batsmen and their scores (4s, 6s, score avg) and bowler into another (overs, maidens, economy, wickets..)

Comment: `echo array_search('Bowler',$content);...elseif($content[$i]=="Bowler")...if(in_array("C Gayle", $content)){echo 'found<br>';} else{echo 'ille<br>';}` is not able to trace it

Comment: That's because `$i` only goes to 58, not 59. Try adjusting your `for` loop as suggested...

Comment: i've checked till 62, but not able to trace it...can you pls compile what i mean and check

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean by trace in this instance.

Comment: echo $content[59] .'<br><br>'; prints the element 'bowler' but am not able to detect it by conditional statements. All I need is to make two arrays of which one should contain batsmen and their scores (4s, 6s, score avg) and bowler into another (overs, maidens, economy, wickets..)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the DOMDocument class myself, but I noticed that the `<td>` with "Bowler" in it actually contains `<b>Bowler</b>`. Have you tried checking for that string? If not, are you sure that HTML tags have been removed?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
for($i=0;$i<=59;$i++)
```

If you say <59 it will access till 58 th elements and not 59th.

Comment: Sir, I've used all permutations possible. My issue is am not able to trace the element "bowler" through conditional statements, i can see it when printed. 
echo $content[59] .'<br><br>'; prints the element 'bowler' but am not able to detect it by conditional statements. All I need is to make two arrays of which one should contain batsmen and their scores (4s, 6s, score avg) and bowler into another (overs, maidens, economy, wickets..)

Comment: `echo array_search('Bowler',$content);...elseif($content[$i]=="Bowler")...if(in_array("C Gayle", $content)){echo 'found<br>';} else{echo 'ille<br>';}` is not able to trace it

Answer (score 1):

please check the array string there is blank space after Bowler string ( [59]=> string(8) "Bowler " )

Comment: yes there are some blank strings at some lines but it doesnt matter to me